# Ubuntu 19.10 Wifi Bluetooth not working RTL8723de

Tags: 19.10, realtek-wireless

Currently after some tries that I can't even remember, I got my wifi working. Nevertheless, I have the annoying extremely weak signal problem (cannot solve by changing antenna) and Bluetooth is actually not working at all.

Can I get some help in troubleshooting please???

Comment: I do have the same problem with my Bluetooth device.